# Why can't casting an address to int* be an lvalue but casting to a struct pointer can?

Tags: c++, c

I suspect this is true for all primitive types in C/C++.

For example, if you do this:

```
((unsigned int*)0x1234) = 1234;
```

The compiler will not let it pass. Whereas if you do this

```
((data_t*)0x1234 )->s = 1234;
```

where `data_t is a struct`, the compiler allows it.

This seems to be the case for at least two compilers I experimented on, one ARM GCC, one TDM-GCC.

Why is this?

Comment: In the second case, you are not assigning the value to the pointer but to a structure member.

Comment: What do you imagine the first line to do? It is also a type mismatch, as well as trying to modify a value. Maybe you meant `*((unsigned int*)0x1234) = 1234;`

Comment: You basically want to assign `1234` to the integer constant `0x1234`. Similar to 2 = 3 which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 7):

The first code snippet doesn't work because the left hand side is not an lvalue.  It is only a pointer value, and pointers by themselves are not lvalues.

The second code snippet works because a pointer is being dereferenced, and a dereferenced pointer *is* an lvalue.  It may not be immediately clear from the syntax this is the case, so let's rewrite this:

```
((data_t*)0x1234 )->s = 1234;
```

As:

```
(*(data_t*)0x1234).s = 1234;
```

Now we can see that the value which is casted to a pointer is dereferenced to an lvalue of struct type, and a member of that struct is subsequently accessed and assigned to.

This is described in section 6.5.2.3p4 of the C standard regarding the `->` operator:

> A postfix expression followed by the `->` operator and an identifier
>   designates a member of  a  structure  or  union  object.  **The  value
>   is  that  of  the  named  member  of  the  object  to which the first
>   expression points, and is an lvalue.** If the first expression is a
>   pointer to a  qualified  type,  the  result  has  the  so-qualified 
>   version  of  the  type  of  the  designated member.

Regarding the first snippet, section 6.5.4p5 regarding the typecast operator states:

> Preceding  an  expression  by  a  parenthesized  type  name  converts 
>   the  value  of  the expression to the named type.  This construction is
>   called a cast. <sup>104)</sup> A cast that specifies no conversion has
>   no effect on the type or value of an expression.

Where footnote 104 states:

> **A cast  does  not  yield  an  lvalue.**   Thus, a cast  to  a  qualified
>   type  has  the  same  effect  as  a  cast  to  the unqualified version
>   of the type.

So this describes why the first snippet won't compile but the second snippet will.

However, treating an arbitrary value as a pointer and dereferencing it is implementation defined behavior at best, and most likely undefined behavior.

Comment: Pointers are lvalues, but constants aren't.

Comment: @user207421 In C, pointer *objects* are lvalues, but not pointers in general.  For example, the result of the `&` operator is a pointer but is not an lvalue per 6.5.3.2p3.

Comment: @dbush "lvalue" is a property of an expression, not an object

Comment: @M.M True, so instead of "pointer objects are lvalues" it would be more correct to say "expressions that evaluate to objects, including pointer objects, are lvalues"

Answer (score 6):

Your examples are:

```
((unsigned int*)0x1234) = 1234;
((data_t*)0x1234 )->s = 1234;
```

Neither `((unsigned int*)0x1234)` nor `((data_t*)0x1234 )` is an lvalue, and you can't assign to either of them.

More generally, the prefix of `->` doesn't have to be an lvalue. But `prefix->member` is always an lvalue, whether `prefix` is or not. Similarly, `*p` is an value whether `p` is an lvalue or not.